# 16.04 Updates list sizes

Tags: 16.04, updates

First I would like to say that I am loving the new updates tab in software center and how it separates updates into categories that you can update individually and lists what is available in those updates.

Now I am not sure if this is the right place to bring this up but is there a way that we can get this to show how big each update is in MB.  I ask this because I have to update one of my machines through tethering over my phone so I have to keep an eye on data.

The ability to see this through CLI updates would be awesome as well for the server side, if there is already a command to see that info I would like to know it.